# Ajax response with two open session

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to build a chat application using short polling with ajax/php.

the problem that I have is when a user is connected in two devices (or two open session) he doesent receive a notification that he received a message.

is that problem related to the Ajax?

Comment: Please show your efforts, what you have done. @axolagabe